# Lazy Initialiazation Exception in Child collections

Tags: java, database, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity class like below

```
@Table(name = "PARENT")
public class Parent implements Comparable<Parent>, Serializable, Cloneable {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "seq-gen")
@GenericGenerator(name = "seq-gen", strategy = "native",
        parameters = {@Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "id_seq")})
private Long id;


@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@BatchSize(size = 50)   
@SortNatural
private SortedSet<Child> child  = new TreeSet<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@BatchSize(size = 50)   
@SortNatural
private SortedSet<Child> child  = new TreeSet<>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@BatchSize(size = 50)   
@SortNatural
private SortedSet<Second> second = new TreeSet<>();
```

}

And child entity as below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD")

public class Child implements Comparable<Object>, Serializable, Cloneable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "seq-gen")
@GenericGenerator(name = "seq-gen", strategy = "native",
        parameters = {@Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "child_id_seq")})
private Long id;

@ManyToOne()
@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
@JoinColumn(name = "parentId", nullable = false)
private Parent parent;
```

}

I am calling a child in a service method from the session

```
public Child getChild(final Long id,) throws Exception {
    try {
        Child child = (Child) getHibernateTemplate().execute(new HibernateCallback<Child>() {

            /* (non-Javadoc)
             * @see org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateCallback#doInHibernate(org.hibernate.Session)
             */
            public Child doInHibernate(Session session) throws HibernateException {

                Child child = (Child)session.get(Child.class, id);

                if(child != null) {
                    Parent parent = child.Parent();

                    if(step.getParent() != null) {
                        Hibernate.initialize(parent);
                        if (parent.getSecond () != null) {
                            Hibernate.initialize(parent.getSecond());
                        }
                    }                                       
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting Lazy Initialization exception at

`if (parent.getSecond () != null) {`

I have tried by adding

`@Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)`

in both Parent and Child classes, but no success and we have strict rule not to use EAGER. Please help me to solve the above issue.

Comment: I think you can just remove non null check

Comment: Or use Hibernate.isInitialized(parent.getSEcond())

Comment: The answer depends if you want to be pre-fetched or do you want lazy initialization to work.

Comment: `if (parent.getSecond () != null) {` this line should not throw `LazyInitializationException` at all because no initialization usually occurs when you call a getter. Getter will return a reference to a lazy collection instance. If you try to iterate the collection or get its size then Hibernate will try to initialize the collection.

Comment: when I remove the `if(parent.getSecond() != null)`  I am getting 
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateSystemException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: could not initialize proxy - no Session